# How to use 'Polyline'

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, polyline, folium

Using jupyter Notebook/python3

I want to use polyline with marker but it doesn't work

```
map = folium.Map(location=[37.4601908, 126.4406957])

for index,lat in enumerate(place_lat):
    folium.Marker([lat, 
                   place_lng[index]],
                  popup=('patient3 \n 74contacts'),
                 icon = folium.Icon(color='green',icon='plus')).add_to(map)
    folium.Polyline(color='red').add_to(map)

map
```

I thought Polyline is in folium

But error says

```
AttributeError: module 'folium' has no attribute 'Polyline'
```

How can I use polyline?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [docs](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.vector_layers.PolyLine), you should use `PolyLine`.

For example:

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[37.4601908, 126.4406957],
               zoom_start=15)

place_lat = [37.4601928, 37.4593108, 37.4641108, 37.4611508]
place_lng = [126.4406957, 126.4432957, 126.4476917, 126.4423957]

points = []
for i in range(len(place_lat)):
    points.append([place_lat[i], place_lng[i]])

for index,lat in enumerate(place_lat):
    folium.Marker([lat, 
                   place_lng[index]],
                  popup=('patient{} \n 74contacts'.format(index)),
                 icon = folium.Icon(color='green',icon='plus')).add_to(m)
folium.PolyLine(points, color='red').add_to(m)

m
```

[image]